# Java ArrayList toString & update list after user deletes name from list

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, arraylist, tostring

1. Use toString method of ArrayList Class to print the ArrayList.
2. Ask the user for a name to delete from the list. If the name was not found in the list, print a message saying that the name was not in the list. If it was found, delete the name, and print the current list.

I cannot seem to get the toString method to work, nor the "If the list was found, delete the name, and print the current list".

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Open the file
    File file = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    // Read until the end of the file
    while(inputFile.hasNext()){
        //String str = inputFile.nextLine();
        list.add(inputFile.next());
        System.out.println(list.toString() + " " + list.size());
    }
    inputFile.close();

    // Add a name to the end of the list
    list.add("Michael"); 
    System.out.println("\nMichael is added to the end of the list: \n" + list.toString());

    // Add a name to the list in position 2
    list.add(2, "Lucy"); 
    System.out.println("\nLucy is added to the list as the third name: \n" + list.toString());

    // Find the indexOf Michael 
    System.out.println("\nindexOf Michael is: " + list.indexOf("Michael"));

    // Replace Michael with Mike
    list.set(11, "Mike");
    System.out.println("\nReplace Michael with Mike: \n" + list.toString());

    // Ask user for a name to delete from the list
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What name would you like to delete from the list? ");
    String deleteName = input.nextLine();

    // If name not found then display message
    boolean found = false;
    if(found == false)
        System.out.println("The name is not on the list");

    // If name found then delete name and show current ArrayList
    for(String a: list){
        if(a.compareTo(deleteName) == 0){
            list.remove(a);
            System.out.println(a + " was deleted from the list. Here is the new list:  \n" +
                               list.toString());
        }
    }
    // String str = (String)nameList.get(0);
}

// Use toString method of the ArrayList Class. 
public String toString()
{
    return list.toString();
}
```

Comment: Define "I can not". What do you expect the code to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: "cannot find symbol - variable list" for toString(), and I'm not sure how else I would go about returning the list via the toString().

Comment: And what is the line number of the error? Is there a variable list available at that line? Where is the line variable defined? Do you really think a variable defined in a method is available to any other method? The code of the main method already uses the toString() method of ArrayList, as asked. I'm not sure why you want to define a toString() method in your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `delete` part

try

```
if (list.contains (deleteName)) 
{
    list.remove (deleteName);
}
```

It is not necessary to loop through.

Also to make `list` visible to the `toString` method, make it a class field.

Answer (score 0):

First problem I see is your list isn't global so your toString() doesn't have any access to it.

As for the delete case it looks fine to me.